# Unable to show custom block

Tags: magento-1.8

I followed this tutorial to create the custom block in magento

http://www.gravitywell.co.uk/blog/post/how-to-creating-your-own-custom-block-in-magento

But nothing is showed when I open up home page or any other page. I have searched alot on web but unable to solve the issue.

The above tutorial did not mention where to create layout.xml file but I have created it at:

```
app\design\frontend\gravitywell\example\layout\layout.xml
```

It has just following code:

```
<block type="gravitywellexample/menu" name="menu" as="menu" template="gravitywell/menu.phtml" />
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Here is `local.xml` at `app\design\frontend\gravitywell\example\layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="gravitywellexample/menu" name="menu" as="menu" template="gravitywell/menu.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This is `config.xml` at `app\code\local\Gravitywell\Example\etc`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
 <modules>
    <Gravitywell_Example>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Gravitywell_Example>
 </modules>
    <global>
    <blocks>
        <gravitywellexample>
            <class>Gravitywell_Example_Block</class>
        </gravitywellexample>
    </blocks>
</global>

</config>
```

Here is `menu.phtml` at `app\design\frontend\gravitywell\example\template\gravitywell`:

> #### Hello Sir

Comment: try to rename layout.xml to local.xml

Comment: To get the full picture we would need to see your module's `config.xml`, `layout.xml` and the `.phtml` that your child is being called in.

Comment: Required code added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the tutorial that you followed except that it does not mention what layout.xml means.

Anyways, in order for you to solve your issue try to follow the following steps:

- Make sure your new Magento extension is enabled by going to: `admin -> System -> Advanced -> Advanced tab -> Disabled Modules Output`
- Make sure to clear Magento cache if its enabled. Flush magento cache from here: `admin -> System -> Cache Management`
- Create local.xml file in this folder `app\design\frontend\gravitywell\example\layout\local.xml`
- Place this block `<block type="gravitywellexample/menu" name="menu" as="menu" template="gravitywell/menu.phtml" />` under any existing block as the following sample:

**local.xml example**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="gravitywellexample/menu" name="menu" as="menu" template="gravitywell/menu.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

You can replace `<reference name="left">` with `<reference name="right">` or `<reference name="header">` depends on where you want to place your new block.

- Finally, make sure you change Magento design package to `gravitywell`, design template to `example` and layout to `example` from `admin -> System -> General -> Design`

Comment: I have renamed layout.xml to local.xml but nothing happened. Secondly, I also tried the solution of Aboodred1 but it also does not solve the problem..

Comment: Here is local.xml at app\design\frontend\gravitywell\example\layout\local.xml:  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="gravitywellexample/menu" name="menu" as="menu" template="gravitywell/menu.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>

Comment: @MFI did you add any content in menu.phtml file or you left it empty?

Comment: @MFI also did you change magento package and theme to gravitywell/example?

Comment: Yes I have added h1 heading in menu.phtml

Comment: you mean changing of magento package and theme in admin? If yes, I tried by entering the name of package in admin->system->design but it also did not work..

Comment: @MFI did put package name as 'gravitywell' and templates as 'example' and layout as 'example' case sensitive

Comment: I have renamed all the folders to Sentence case now. But no success. Also, currently, "Current Package Field" in admin contains "default", I changed it as well but no success, so I restored it default.

Comment: @MFI hmmm, then try to copy `gravitywell/menu.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/` and copy `local.xml` to `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/`

Comment: I copied at your given locations but still no success..I am surprised how difficult it is to create a simple block in magento.

Comment: @MFI I implemented this solution before I posted it as an answer, and it worked for me. I guess you might have a typo or php error or xml error that prevent the block to show.

Comment: Is there a way to see the error in magento? One of my colleague also implemented this solution but he has same problem as well..We both can't do the same typo error. You can see the code of files in question with exact locations and suggest based on that if something is missing..I appreciate your help..

Comment: @MFI add this line `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"` to your .htaccess file. You should see all kind of errors. Other suggestion, try to break local.xml file structure by making it invalid xml structure.

Comment: I put it these values but still it's not showing anything on home page or any other page. How to check if magento is loading the block or not?

Comment: @MFI try to put invalid php code in `app/code/local/Gravitywell/Example/Block/Menu.php`, if you got an error, this mean Magento is recognizing your extension. Also in local.xml within reference tags add open tag like this `<hello>` don't close it. You should get error if magento is reading layout xml file. Make sure to clear magento cache each time you change anything. Also remove cache folder under `magento-root/var/cache`

Comment: I add invalid code in Menu.php and magento gives error. It means it is recognizing my extension. Secondly, I added <hello> tag in local.xml without closing the tag but in this case magento did not give any error. It means magento is not reading local.xml, right? Now what should I do?

Comment: Also, I have disabled the cache and I also removed the cached folder from var but no success

Comment: there is a good news, finally it showed the output..I put the <hello> tag without closing in app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/local.xml and it showed the error. I then changed the <reference name="header"> to <reference name="right"> and it showed the output. But the question is still there why it is not reading from app/design/frontend/gravitywell/example/layout/local.xml? Because if I upgrade magento in future, the folder app/desing/frontend/default/default/layout/local.xml will be override..So this does not look permanent solution.

Comment: @MFI finally! .... the reason why its not reading local.xml from `gravitywell/example` because you need to change magento  theme package, template and layout to read from the new theme.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to include a new layout.xml file:

## local.xml

local.xml in `design/frontend/<yourpackage>/<yourtheme>/layout` is loaded  automatically, therefore the tipp by Aboodred should solve your problem

This solution is normally used to add specific blocks to your layout, independant from an extension.

## module layout xml

If you want to include your own layout.xml inside your module with your own name, you have to define it in `<Company>/<Module>/etc/config.xml`, like this:

```
<config>
  <frontend>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <mymodule> <!-- this node name needs to be unique through out all config.xml files -->
          <file>mymodule.xml</file>
        </mymodule>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

## More background

Your layout files are loaded here: `\Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update::getFileLayoutUpdatesXml`, the local.xml is loaded at least.

Comment: I think your answer is a little bit advance ;)